# Dynamically creating Arraylist based on a criteria and adding data to it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Arralist containing a group of objects in which each objects has fields(deptname,year,count). I know that we can create arraylist dynamically using for loop

```
     List<List<ReportEPVO>> dataList = new ArrayList<List<ReportEPVO>>();

     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         List<ReportEPVO> tempList = new ArrayList<ReportEPVO>();
         dataList.add(tempList);
     }
```

My requirement is that  for example: there are objects with year field 2013,2014,2015 respectively.  i want to create arraylists dynamically and add objects with same year field on same arraylist.  any help?.  please dont downvote  i am new to datastructures..

This may be the code to add objects with yearfield 2013 to arraylist named temp13.

```
    List<ReportEPVO> temp13 = new ArrayList<ReportEPVO>();
    for(ReportEPVO re : reportEPvo) {
        if(re.getJoinYear().equals("2013") )
            temp13.add(re);
    }
```

How can i create  arraylists dynamically to store objects for example yearfields with 2013 , 2014 etc ?

Comment: Please show the code you have written to achieve that.

Comment: please abbreviate with an real example only.. you are not too specific to clear your view. Thanx

Comment: If you are trying to group records based on the value of a field you should look at using a Map.

Comment: try to check year before adding element in arraylist

Comment: People don't downvote questions because of the difficulty, they downvote because of not enough research, off-topic, or unclear.

Comment: Maybe using a `Map` would better fit your needs `Map<String, List<ReportEPVO>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();`. That way the key is your `Year` and you have a `List` for all your entries.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap  i edited my question.please check it

Comment: Everyone please check my question again

Comment: @kuttanpillai I gave you an answer. If you accept it you will be able to upvote both my answers to your questions.

Comment: @xenteros  will do as soon as a i ve completed running dat code

Comment: @kuttanpillai added print method.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in this situation I will do something like

```
Map<String, List<MyObject> myListMap = new HashMap();

for(MyObject myObject : myObjects){
   List<Object> myObjectList = myListMap.get(myObject.getIndexAttribute());
   if(myObjectList == null){
       myObjectList = new ArrayList();
       myListMap.put(myObject.getIndexAttribute(), myObjectList);
   }
   myObjectList.add(myObject);
}
```

Comment: please dont mind  u need Map<String,List<ReportEPVO>> myListMap = new HashMap();   in the code right?

Comment: okk  but will this code stores objects based on their respective years?

Comment: This code will group records based on the value of the index attribute whatever that is. Each individual value of that filed will be associated with a list of Objects, If that value is always unique then the list size will always be one, otherwise you will get lists of varying sizes. Your question is quite abstract you will need to make it far more specific before any guarantees can be made.

Comment: okk i will make it more specific. the user inputs the "FromYear"  and  "toYear"  i.e  suppose  user inputs 2013 as the fromyear and 2015 as toyear, i want to print out  count of the workers who have worked  in the each department in years 2013,14,15 respectively. i used table join query and  returned the results to an arraylist but  it contains all  counts of workers in 2013,14,15  respectively. so i want to dynamically create arraylists(in this case 3 of them) to store counts and department  based on their respective years.   is my question clear?

Comment: @kuttanpillai is your workers workin 2 years are present twice in the result ? Since you only have a Year field, i guess so ... This solution is good. getIndexAttribute is the getJoinYear(). (the key of the map). This is a general solution, you just need to update with your Object and getter to be able to use it. And code is elegant.

Comment: yea  count of workers  appears multiple times according to the years

Comment: @kuttanpillai Then this is ok, just update this code to match your instance. This will create a list per year and add each instance in the correct list. The way a map works is it use a key to store an instance, in this case, the key is the Year to store a list. Each list will be recovered by the get(instance.getYear..() ).